# Bezier path stroking performance issues

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, performance, macos, bezier

My code goes as following -

```
[[NSColor whiteColor] set];
// `path' is a bezier path with more than 1000 points in it
[path setLineWidth:2];
[path setLineJoinStyle:NSRoundLineJoinStyle];
[path stroke];
// some other stuff...
```

Running the time profiling tool in Instruments it tells me my app is spending 93.5% of the time doing the last line `[path stroke]`, and Quartz Debugger tells me my app is only running at less than 10 fps (another view changing position on top of it is always causing the update).

I'm looking for ways to improve the performance of stroking the bezier path, sometimes paths with more than 1000 points draws very quickly with >60fps, however in some extreme cases even with the same number of points, perhaps if the points are too far from each other (or too dense?) the performance becomes really sluggish.

I'm not sure what I can do about this. I think caching the view as a bitmap rep is helpful, but it can't really help with live resize.

Edit: commenting out the line `[path setLineWidth:2];` certainly helps, but the path looked really too 'thin'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can adjust the flatness of the curve using the method setFlatness:, higher values increase the rendering speed at the expense of accuracy.  You should use a higher value during live resizes, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Back when I asked the Quartz 2D team at Apple about this, they told me that the biggest factor in the performance of stroking a path with a large number of points, is how many times the path intersects itself. There's a lot of work that goes into properly anti-aliasing an intersection.

Comment: The segments are in fact non intersecting (the path represents a graph for data), maybe they are too close together to go over the others.

Comment: If the edges of the rendered segments touch each other, then the rasterizer still has to do that work.

Answer (score 2):

Do you build the path at each draw - does it change from drawing to drawing? It sounds like it does change. There may be caching if you draw the same path over and over, so try creating it and keeping it around until it changes. It may help.

You can also drop down an API level or two. Perhaps CALayer objects may do what you want. In other words - do you really have a 1000 point line that needs to be curved to connect the points? You can do a bunch of CALayer objects to draw line segments.

The math on these processors is fast. You could also perhaps write a math routine to throw out unneeded points, to cut the number from 1000 to about 200 or so, say. The math would try to eliminate points that are close together, etc.

My bet is on the math to throw out points that don't make any visual difference. The flatness thing sounds interesting too - it may be that by going totally flat you are doing line segments.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion on using CALayer objects. I do cache paths until live resize, CPU is fast at doing math indeed, but path stroke is causing a stroke to the computer.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say

> another view changing position on top
>   of it is always causing the update

??

Do you mean that you are not redrawing the view at 60fps? Then that will be why you are not seeing 60fps then.

When

> Instruments it tells me my app is
>   spending 93.5% of the time

doing something, it doesn't mean 'all available' time it means 93.5% of the cpu cycles your app consumed. ie, it could be no time at all. It isn't enough to determine that you need to optimise. I'm not saying you don't need to, or that stroking massive beziers isn't dog slow. Just that alone doesn't mean much.